# Using jQuery to bind an event to AJAX content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that is AJAXed in, thus loads later than the actual page. I would like to know if there is a way to bind an event to the surrounding div (the container div of logged in information).

Basically the container is empty when jQuery(document).ready() runs and gets populated 1-2 seconds after. I would like to run some scripts when this happens - and I'd rather not put the script into the AJAXed content itself.

In short, I want to execute some Javascript when a certain element shows on screen.

Comment: What is the code that loads this menu?

Comment: @Blender it is an extension within Magento and I'd rather not get into that

Comment: define `bind an event`? You can delegate event handlers when page loads... running plugins is a different story

Comment: I just want to run some code when the element shows up.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your script inside `success` function of ajax... success is called whn the ajax  request succeeds...

```
 $.ajax{(
     url:....
     ...
     success:function(result){
           //do your stuff like appeding..
           //your script here
       }
 })
```

it would be easier if you provide us with codes to help you out..

Comment: The ajax content does not use this method & therefore I cannot use the success callback...

Comment: what event you want actually.. click or sumthing ??

Comment: No, I want to run something when an AJAX element shows, without having to rely on an AJAX callback. Just completely standalone, if it is possible.

Comment: You mean to say , something loading or getting data ??

Comment: Almost a way to constantly monitor the page & when content shows up, execute code. I can do it with a timer but obviously ugly.

Comment: please go through the Magento's ajax call.. cause i doubt there is no success call for that...... may be some other events/methods like.. afterSuccess or soemthing